# byte vs str.encode in python3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

I am using python3.5, Let

```
M = '\x09\x00\x00\x00\x01\x89\x02\xdb\xd6\x01\x49\x63\x74'
```

Why is the left part of the following comparison not equal to the right part?

```
> M.encode() == b'\x09\x00\x00\x00\x01\x89\x02\xdb\xd6\x01\x49\x63\x74'
$ FALSE
```

the type of both is `bytes`. How can I reach from `M` to a variable that contains the right part of the above comparison?

Comment: this has been asked before, when you're encoding you're interpreting the string. Looking for a duplicate / a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not an encoding specialist, but whatever the encoding you'll be choosing, if it's not correct, it will interpret characters and the result won't be the same as the bytes object.

It will work with pure ascii, but with your values it doesn't.

One way would be to rebuild the `bytes` object from character codes that `ord` provides:

```
M = '\x09\x00\x00\x00\x01\x89\x02\xdb\xd6\x01\x49\x63\x74'
N = b'\x09\x00\x00\x00\x01\x89\x02\xdb\xd6\x01\x49\x63\x74'

M2 = bytes(map(ord,M))

print(N == M2)
```

yields `True` :)